# select2.js - How to make selection active from data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have the following html code:

```
 <div class='multiWrapper'>
     <select id="multi" class="js-dropdown-from-code">
         <optgroup class='def-cursor' label='Code' data-city='Description'>
             <option data-city="" data-id="0">Select unit...</option>
             <option data-city="New York" data-id="1">USA</option>
             <option data-city="London" data-id="2">UK</option>
         </optgroup>
     </select>
 </div>
```

Where the select is converted into a Select2 dropdown list with two columns.

```
$('#multi').select2({
    width: '100%',
    formatResult: formatResultMulti,
    dropdownCssClass: 'bigdrop'
});
```

Using this functionality.

```
function formatResultMulti(data) {
    var city = $(data.element).data('city');
    var classAttr = $(data.element).attr('class');
    var hasClass = typeof classAttr != 'undefined';
    classAttr = hasClass ? ' ' + classAttr : '';
    var $result = $(
        '<div class="row" style="font-size: 0.8125rem;">' +
        '<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6' + classAttr + '">' + data.text + '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6' + classAttr + '">' + city + '</div>' +
        '</div>'
    );
    return $result;
}
```

All of this is working, my question is when I am trying to load the select2 with a specific value to start.

Normally I would use the $('#multi).val('').trigger('change') to set the value, but as i am using an option group, i am not sure on how to do the same.

Can anyone please rescue me from my ignorance.

UPDATE:

I have added the missing HTML option tags. As you can see I am not using the value tag, but a data attribute data-id.

I have found that using the following works

```
$("#multi option[data-id='30']").prop("selected", true).trigger('change');
```

but it is not setting the underlying values, so on submitting the form, validation is not recognising the change trigger.

Comment: "but it is not setting the underlying values, so on submitting the form, validation is not recognising the change trigger." - not sure what that means? or what you're trying to do exactly? why don't your options have `value='<something>'` set? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using

$("#multi").val("").trigger('change.select2');